# To Develop LMS and Scorm Sequesncing Engine

Tags: scorm

We want a LMS(coded in ASP.NET/vb.net) which is able to import SCORM packages & display it to learner for viewing content. I am totally new to SCORM and have been shifted to this project. I want to know how can I access SCORM Assessment object's (Test) result, like Learner ID, passed/fail, time.

Can you please guide me what will I need to implement in ASP.NET code to accomplish my goal ?

Task that I have done so far is,

Reading a manifest zip file, unzipping the file and get all information from the file(content name,description,items and launching page) and when user clicks on a particular course a pop up window is launching the page.

I eagerly want to know what I can do next to communicate with the LMS with the APIs. Shall I need to develop my own LMS to get the result,If there is a quiz which is running, all I need to know is the no of questions attempted by the user, whether the user is pass or fail and I need to store all information in the database for individual user so that I can review the result afterwards.

So the task remaining.

1. Tracking mechanism to deliver the content.
2. SCORM/LMS sequencing engine that controls the navigation between parts of SCORM conformant course.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

SLK at codeplex provides a good starting point. However, if you are truly wanting to provide an in-house written SCORM play that is fully compliant, you have a major task ahead of you. In essence there are three party you need to fully develop:

CAM - the unzipping process, which it sounds like you have already achieved.

RTE - the javascript host for SCORM, providing the 8 specified methods. Behind this you also need to implement the SCORM object model, which SLC does help with. If you have implemented all of this, then there should be data entries on the data model that indicate completion etc.

SN - the sequencing and navigation processing. This is significantly the most complex part. I am still in the process of trying to implement this, using SLC, and it is hard. It is the completion of this that will potentially give you more information that will enable you to know what has been done.

it is also worth looking at scorm.com, who are a consultancy, but provide a lot of useful information about the scorm standard.

Comment: I am also new to Scorm 2004 4th edition based LMS.
I have taken this task.
Please can you help me here?
I have completed reading CAM , and now i m reading RTE document.

Answer (score 0):

That is true. SCORM is one of these stadarts where you can implement as little as possible. But you will need some of Javascript with a Backend-Script (JSON to the rescue) so you can track the scorm data, and save it your database.

But let me tell you this: This is the easiest task! Making your own course-creator is a whole other beast.

Comment: Please see the question I have posted in the same blog.