# Consuming SCORM Content Package in LMS

Tags: scorm

I am completely new to SCORM and LMS. Basically for now, i just need to play the content package(downloaded from SCORM website) in my project and should be able to communicate with it. I have downloaded the open source LMS DotNetSCORM since i need this in .Net project but that doesn't seem to be working properly. I basically just need a very very simple example where LMS is able to lauch the Content and able to communicate with it through javascript. I have been through adlnet and SCORM websites but all examples just seem to provide Content package and nowhere i have found an LMS that communicates with it. Any help would be valuable for me to get started.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other posts on StackOverflow asking the same question:

- [Want my LMS to be SCORM compatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264543/want-my-lms-to-be-scorm-compatable)
- [Integrate SCORM in LMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159693/integrate-scorm-in-lms)
- [To Develop LMS and Scorm Sequesncing Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211970/to-develop-lms-and-scorm-sequesncing-engine)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237251/import-mechanism-for-scorm-packages
- [Importing SCORM compliant Lesson (imsmanifest.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551315/importing-scorm-compliant-lesson-imsmanifest-xml)

You wrote:

> I basically just need a very very simple example where LMS is able to lauch the Content and able to communicate with it through javascript.

Unfortunately there is nothing simple about integrating SCORM into an LMS. If the course only uses the run-time (the JavaScript portion of SCORM), you can build a wrapper using [Claude Ostyn's mini-runtime](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/singleSCOminiRTEwrap.htm) as a starting point (you'd need to build your own database and have the wrapper point to it).

But if you need to support multiple SCOs, the imsmanifest.xml file, and/or any sequencing or globals, you are embarking on a very long and difficult journey, especially if you're new to LMSs and SCORM.

My advice is to use someone else's product. Find an LMS that already provides SCORM support, or use a product like [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/).